# inotifywait never prints the unmount event

Tags: linux, inotify

From the manual page of `inotifywait`:

```
EVENTS
...
       unmount
              The filesystem on which a watched file or directory resides was unmounted.
              After this event the file or directory is no longer being watched.  Note
              that this event can occur even if it is not explicitly being listened to.
```

I'm trying to make it work without success. The program keeps running after unmounting the watched directory and doesn't print anything.

Prepare the test:

```
cd /tmp/
fallocate -l500M test.img
mkdir -p /media/test
losetup -f test.img
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0
mount /dev/loop0 /media/test
inotifywait -m /media/test &
inotifywait -m /media &
```

Test that other events work:

```
[root@basinsrv tmp]# touch /media/test/xxx
/media/test/ CREATE xxx
/media/test/ OPEN xxx
/media/test/ ATTRIB xxx
/media/test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE xxx
[root@basinsrv tmp]#
```

Unmounting:

```
[root@basinsrv tmp]# umount /media/test
[root@basinsrv tmp]#
```

My system:

```
[root@basinsrv tmp]# uname -a
Linux basinsrv 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 18 15:06:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@basinsrv tmp]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```